# Is copying the /var/lib/mysql directory a good alternative to mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

Since I'm making a full backup of my entire debian system, I was thinking if having a copy of `/var/lib/mysql` directory is a viable alternative to dumping tables with mysqldump.

- are all informations needed contained in that directory?
- can single tables be imported in another mysql?
- can there be problems while restoring those files on a (probably slightly) different mysql server version?

Comment: Doing this for years, no inconsistency!

Comment: Percona has a tool that basically takes this approach for doing "hot backups" of running servers: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- Yes
- Yes if the table is using the MyISAM (default) engine. Not if it's using InnoDB.
- Probably not, and if there is, you just need to execute mysql_upgrade to fix them

To avoid getting databases in a inconsistent state, you can either shutdown MySQL or use LOCK TABLES and then FLUSH TABLES before the backup.  The second solution is a little better because the MySQL server will remain available during the backup (albeit read only).

Comment: Thanks everybody for this solution. It's cut out at least an hour of re-importing time !

And if you want to do it into one instruction: Type "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;".

Comment: Can you go into details on the answer for "can single tables be imported into another mysql"? "Yes so long as it's MyISAM" is a rather sparse answer.

Answer (score 6):

This approach is only going to work safely if you shut the database down first. Otherwise you could well end up in an inconsistent state afterwards. Use the /etc/init.d/mysql stop command first. You can then restart it after the backup is taken.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly OK as long as you shut down the MySQL sever first and use exactly the same version to retrieve the "backup". Otherwise it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete discussion of the 2 strategies, you need to read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/backup-types.html

The currently best free and open-source solution seems to be Percona's: http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with a strong NO.

From my experience, backing up/restoring raw mysql data files can be used only on the same os/server version. It does not work cross platform (eg. ubuntu/macos) with same server versions nor if mysql server versions are different on same platform.

[Percona XtraBackup (innobackupex)](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) from Percona MySQL distro will let you do live & differential mysql backup and serve you the backup files that can be restored by copying to `/var/lib/mysql/`. You need to be running Percona Server for MySQL to use all of this.