# Reclaim disk space from failed insert

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I foolishly tried to add a column to a table that I did not have enough space on disk to copy and had to kill it and expand my RDS instance's storage capacity to avert a site crash.  I would like to do it again (this time with enough disk space) but I can't seem to get back to my pre-query free storage levels.  My query was to create a table like a giant table, add a column and then insert the entire contents of the old table together with null into the new table.  I tried `CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log;` and `CALL mysql.rds_rotate_general_log;` but judging by my AWS Cloudwatch panel, I'm still down ~10GB from my pre-query levels.  No lines were successfully inserted into the new table.  Is there some "clear hdd cache" command or something like that?  Since it's RDS, I don't have access to the instance that's running it but I do have master user and RDS CLI access.

**EDIT**: It seems my problem may be related to giant `ibdata` files but since I don't have root access, I can't really execute the solutions mentioned in  [How to shrink/purge ibdata1 file in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to drop the new table.  I didn't think that anything was stored in the new table because `select count(*) from new_table;` returned 0 but I guess the temporary data was tied in to the new table anyway.  I'm not sure how exactly this works from a database structural point of view but fortunately it did what I wanted.

Bottom line: killed inserts still use storage space.

If somebody can explain why this is the case, it would be helpful for the future.