# can we removed live ibdata1 file of mysql for myisam engine

Tags: mysql

Can we remove ibdata1 file of mysql for myisam engine without downtime?
actually it's size is more then 200 GB.
will it effect the live mysql server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shrink/purge ibdata1 file in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql)

Comment: How many InnoDB tables do you have? (Please run `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';`)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete ibdata on a running database.

If you want minimal downtime though, you should check : http://erikimh.com/how-to-shrink-an-ibdata1-file-with-minimal-mysql-downtime/