# Database needs to have size scaled down

Tags: mysql

Our DBA is on holiday, and since I know 'a bit' of MySQL, they've asked me to fix this.  The data slice is at 99%, and I need to know what to get rid of.

[root@servername]# find . -type f -size +1000000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
./mysql/stuffInDatabase.ibd: 6.8G

Thing is, I've never done this before, and so don't know where to start.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Which database do I need to use, the production one or the information_schema?  Which query do I use?  Do I need to dump and then reimport?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql

Comment: Make a good backup before doing anything else.

Comment: This is more appropriately asked over at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for these comments, guys.  I have just asked the question over at dba.stackexchange.  Oh, and some of the files are from reports, if that helps.