# Restarting linux destroys mysql tables

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I recently had a 8GB ibdata1 file in `/var/lib/mysql` because one of my databases previously got spammed by 8GB worth of data.  I deleted that spammed database, and running the following query in MySQL terminal

```
SELECT table_schema "Database Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024  "Database Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
```

yielded 100MB worth of combined data in my database.  However my ibdata1 file was still a hefty 8GB.  So then I followed the instructions of the accepted answer here to regenerate my ibdata1 and log files:

[How to shrink/purge ibdata1 file in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql)

This worked.

However, as soon as I reboot my Linux server, many of the databases (but not all) in my MySQL server suddenly have zero data.  I repeated the instructions in the accepted answer with and without `innodb_file_per_table` in the appropriate place in my `my.conf` file, but it still doesn't prevent the destruction of MySQL databases after a Linux reboot.  I notice that my ibdata1 file never exceeds 10MB anymore.

Right now, I've re-imported all my databases, and although things are working, i'm worried about losing all my data the moment the server needs to reboot.

Why is this happening? How do I prevent the destruction of MySQL databases after a Linux server reboot?

Comment: Does the schema of the table still limit its size? Also, is 8GB of disk space really worth all this effort?

Comment: What is the engine you are using?

Comment: the schema of tables do not have a limit to size.  The engine is mostly innodb.  Some are myisam.

Comment: I don't think your database problem is related to the reboot operation. I think it is most probably related to purge operation. Did you delete mysql database during purge?