# Why Magento is taking huge disk space

Tags: magento, diskspace

My magento store is taking huge disk space and it has exceeded 7.5 GB disk space. I have over 12k products.

I have done following but it has not made any significant effect

- Clear all database cache table
- Removed files under var/media/import
- Cleared var/cache
- Removed files under var/log and var/reports

Comment: What's filling up the space? Do you have a shell on the machine? If so, can you run `du`? I like to do `du -h --max-depth=1` and then go from there to find out where it's getting eaten up.

Comment: To add up to @Mike comment, also try (with `du`) to get the size of your mysql `ibdata` file, and... cry if that is your problem, because even if you did clean a lot of records by clearing some of the database, you cannot easily reclaim that space : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql

Comment: Another thing is that I notice you didn't mention media/catalog - if you have a lot of products like you mention, and they all have images, that can fill up quick. I have around 1k products for example, and my media/catalog directory is approaching 1GB total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok because with 12k products you have 12k of images at least. if average of the image of your product is 200kb, so you might be consume **2.4GB** for only your product image. Check your this directory

```
magento/media/*
```

that one have many uncompressed images from your products.

**you should**

- Minify all images to compress your large disk space used. try [jpegmini.com](http://jpegmini.com)
- Minify the [js](http://jscompress.com/) and [css](http://cssminifier.com/) that never be updated recently. to get the faster performance also to your website.