# How to shrink ibdata1 file size after moving to innodb_file_per_table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've followed the instruction in this thread ( https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/what-is-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql ) successfully but after 2 months the ibdata1 continues to grow. I've tried optimizing tables but it didn't reclaimed lost storage space. How do i shrink ibdata1 file size? Is there any way to delete it safely?

Comment: There are several uses for ibdata1 other than tables.  How big is it now?  If it is a few megabytes, I would not worry.  Also, what is the value in my.cnf for its initial size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you want to reclaim the space from `ibdata1` you actually have to
>   delete the file:
>
> 1. Do a `mysqldump` of all databases, procedures, triggers etc **except the `mysql` and `performance_schema` databases**
> 2. Drop all databases **except the above 2 databases**
> 3. Stop mysql
> 4. Delete `ibdata1` and `ib_log` files
> 5. Start mysql
> 6. Restore from dump

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql)

Comment: do i have to do this again? i have done this 2 months ago. or is this the only way?

Comment: @ChristianBurgos:- You have to repeat process again :)