# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file '/tmp/MYHKgYpv' (Errcode: 28)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have installed [Visitor](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) Module Drupal 7. I have viewed the reports using www.domain.com/visitors.  All the reports are working well. But when i view the user activity report it shows below error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3 Error writing file
>   '/tmp/MYHKgYpv' (Errcode: 28): SELECT u.name AS name, u.uid AS uid,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT v.visitors_id) AS hits, COUNT(DISTINCT n.nid) AS nodes,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT c.cid) AS comments FROM {users} u LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   {visitors} v ON u.uid=v.visitors_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN {node} n ON
>   u.uid=n.uid LEFT OUTER JOIN {comment} c ON u.uid=c.uid WHERE
>   (visitors_date_time BETWEEN :db_condition_placeholder_0 AND
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) GROUP BY u.name, u.uid, v.visitors_uid,
>   n.uid, c.uid ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1451606400
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1452556799 ) in
>   PagerDefault->execute() (line 79 of
>   /home/legalmon/public_html/includes/pager.inc).

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Give the mysqld write permissions in /tmp. Usually this directory is writable for everyone, if your system uses selinux this might be a problem.

Comment: I already gave full write permission for /tmp folder. but still it shows the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should continuously check your /tmp folder size while triggering "USER REPORT Query".

If /tmp directory is 100% utilized you would experience this error.

Solution is to mount some GB's to /tmp directory or set new location of MySQL tmp.

To setting up New location:

```
Create a directory anywhere you have enough space(can be the "/" root directory)

# mkdir /home/mysqltmp

Give write permissions

# chmod 1777 /home/mysqltmp

Open MY.CNF File

# /etc/my.cnf 

Add below line under the [mysqld] section and save the file

# tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp

Restart MySQL

# /etc/init.d/mysql restart

Check new location

# mysqladmin var | grep tmpdir

This should show following return.

| slave_load_tmpdir                       | /home/mysqltmp
| tmpdir                                  | /home/mysqltmp
```

Done !!

Try refresh the Page.

Answer (score 1):

First, **check with `df -h` if the storage device is nearly full**, if that's the case, then you need to free up some space.

**Deleting old databases may be solution, but if you don't see a change in free space after the purge, then you need to do the following:**

There's a common problem with some MySQL configurations in which all databases are stored in a single file called `ibdata1`. What happens is that when you delete old databases this file does **not** shrink automatically.

Check the size of the files in `/var/lib/mysql/` and if you see that `ibdata1` size doesn't change after deleting some old databases, then you need to do some clean up.

Steps:

1. **Backup** your databases
2. Delete your databases
3. Delete ibdata1 using `rm /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`
4. Delete ib_logfile(s) using `rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`
5. Restart MySQL with `service mysql restart`
6. Import your backed up databases.

Now, there should be enough space for `/tmp` to grow and execute your queries!

Good luck!

**Notes:**

For more details on the purging visit John P's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456885/2188595